# GitHub Pages - Display Text Randomly Selected from List

Tags: javascript, random, github-pages

I have a personal Github page and I'd like to create a static list of quotations and then every time someone visits my site, have one of those quotations be sampled uniformly at random and then displayed on the main page. I know very little about web development (especially Javascript). How can I do this most straightforwardly?

Comment: Where are you having problems?  Is it in the random number generation?

Comment: I have zero idea how Javascript works, how to create a list of strings, how to randomly sample it, how to display the sampled string. If this was a different programming language, I'd be fine, but I know nothing about Javascript or even whether it's necessary here

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is the most simple possible example of achieving this. It consists of an array of quotes, a line for selecting one quote at random, and a `document.write` call, which writes the quote straight into the document where this script is executed. You can copy paste this snippet into your HTML page (somewhere in the body) and it should work out of the box.

```html
<script>
var quotes = ["quote 1", "quote 2<br>with html line breaks"]
var selected_quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]
document.write(selected_quote)
</script>
```

Note that StackOverflow is a site for developers. Users here are expected to do their due diligence in learning the relevant languages, libraries and tools before asking questions. There is nowadays heaps of amazing resources that can help you with learning anything.